# conversationId - Value can't be NULL

Tags: javascript, microsoft-graph-api, office-js, office-addins

In a Word-addin I'm am trying to fetch data from AAD with the help of ADAL and microsoft.graph. Here is the code:

from app.js

```
var app = (function () {
"use strict";

window.config = {
instance: 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/',
tenant: '<TENANT>',
clientId: '<CLIENTID>',
redirectUri: '<THE-APP-ADDRESS>',
postLogoutRedirectUri: window.location.origin,
endpoints: {
     officeGraph: 'https://graph.microsoft.com',
},
callback: userSignedIn,
popUp: true,
cacheLocation: 'localStorage'

};

function signIn() {
   authContext.login();
}

function userSignedIn(err, token) {
  console.log('userSignedIn called');
//   showWelcomeMessage();
  if (!err) {
      console.log("token: " + token);
      showWelcomeMessage();
  }
  else {
      console.error("error: " + err);
  }
 }

 function showWelcomeMessage() {
  var authContext = new AuthenticationContext(config);

    var $userDisplay = $(".app-user");
    var $signInButton = $(".app-login");
    var $signOutButton = $(".app-logout");

    // Check For & Handle Redirect From AAD After Login
    var isCallback = authContext.isCallback(window.location.hash);
    authContext.handleWindowCallback();

    if (isCallback && !authContext.getLoginError()) {
        window.location = authContext._getItem(authContext.CONSTANTS.STORAGE.LOGIN_REQUEST);
    }
```

and main.js

```
 function getDataFromSelection() {
    var baseEndpoint = 'https://graph.microsoft.com';
    var authContext = new AuthenticationContext(config);

    Office.context.document.getSelectedDataAsync(Office.CoercionType.Text,
        function (asyncResult) {
            if (asyncResult.status === Office.AsyncResultStatus.Succeeded) {

                authContext.acquireToken(baseEndpoint, function (error, token) {
                    if (error || !token) {
                        app.showNotification("Ingen token: ", "Du får logga in igen." + error); // + error
                    }
                    //var email = authContext._user.userName;
                    var url = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/" + config.tenant + "/me";

                    var html = "<ul>";
                    $.ajax({
                        beforeSend: function (request) {
                            request.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json");
                        },
                        type: "GET",
                        url: url,
                        dataType: "json",
                        headers: {
                            'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token,
                        }
                    }).done(function (response) {

                        html += getPropertyHtml("Namn", response.displayName);
                        html += getPropertyHtml("Titel", response.jobTitle);
                        html += getPropertyHtml("Avdelning", response.officeLocation);
                        html += getPropertyHtml("Telefon jobb", response.businessPhones);
                        $("#results").html(html);
                        return postDataToContentControlers(response);


                    }).fail(function (response) {
                       // app.showNotification('Inloggningen slutade att fungera!', 'Du får logga ut och prova att logga in igen'); //response.responseText
                    }).always(function () {
                        console.log("AJAX is done!!")
                    })


                });
            } else {
                app.showNotification('Error:', 'Något gick fel. Du får logga in igen.'); //result.error.message
            }
        }
    );
}
```

On local wordklient it works but on Word online (Office 365 Pro Plus v.1609)
I get this when running the function getDataFromSelection();

[Error from console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ASkWG.jpg)

And right Before I login and i get confirmed and a token:

[image: Token]

the parameter ConversationId is handled when you use microsoft-graph to GET mail-messages. Every mail has a conversationId... Why is it complaining about that regarding a GET against https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me ?

Does anyone know how to get around this problem or Point me in the right direction? Thanks =)

EDIT: And I forgot to mention that this works online on Google Chrome but on Microsoft Edge The popup doesn't work at all regarding login Before even fetching any data. Only popup the addin again.

Comment: If you're looking to incorporate Graph into your add-in, I would suggest looking at [Enable SSO in an add-in](https://dev.office.com/docs/add-ins/develop/sso-in-office-add-ins). It currently in Preview but long-term this is absolutely where you want to end up.

Comment: Thanks Marc =) Well I been checking that out and it seems great =). Do you know how long it will take until its past preview?

Comment: Well, without any answers and suggestions I am now trying out office-js-helpers and tough the configurations seems to be simpler I have run into some problems. I will write a new question for that.